# Swing, achieving components wrapping round onto next line when space constrained with BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I had hoped to create a sublcass of JPanel that would retain a fixed height and width, within which i could add a series of components that would appear sequentially according to the X or Y axis, wrapping round onto the next line below where space was not available on the current line.

Unfortunatley the BoxLayout seems like it is intended to simply lay out components along the X or Y axis in a line. This seems counterintuitive however, since the documentation describes it as like the FlowLayout with additional functionality. Thus surely i assume there must be a way to achive what i am hoping to?

Answer (score 1):

> since the documentation describes it as like the FlowLayout with additional functionality.

It doesn't say anything about wrapping. So why would you expect this additional functionality to be wrapping?. Reread the tutorial for the supported functionality.

In any case you do want to us a `FlowLayout` because it does support wrapping. However the preferred size of a panel using a FlowLayout always assumes a single row. So to get around this limitation you can use the [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) on your panel.